# Cucumber not able to read the definition file

Tags: java, maven, selenium, junit, cucumber

I am a beginner in Cucumber and i have written a basic tests for login and going to the homepage using in a maven project. I suspect there is some consistency issue with POM.xml.

Please find below the files 
I have tried with multiple combinations for the dependencies in pom file but seems the issue persists.

1) stepdefination file

```
package StepDefinition;

import org.junit.Assert;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import io.cucumber.java.en.Given;
import io.cucumber.java.en.Then;
import io.cucumber.java.en.When;


public class loginStepDefinition {

    WebDriver driver;


@Given("^User is already on login page$")
  public void user_already_on_login_page(){
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","/Users/nilesh.gupta/Desktop/chromedriver" );
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("https://classic.crmpro.com");

   }
@When("^Tittle of login page is Free CRM$")
public void tittle_login_page_is_Free_CRM() {
    String tittle = driver.getTitle();
    System.out.println("tittle is : " + tittle);
    Assert.assertEquals("#1 Free CRM for Any Business: Online Customer Relationship Software", tittle);
}
@Then("^User enters username and password$")
public void user_enters_username_and_password() {
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div/div[3]/form/div/input[1]\n" )).sendKeys("naveenk");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div/div[3]/form/div/input[2]\n" )).sendKeys("test@123");
}

@Then("^User clicks on login button$")
public void user_clicks_on_login_button() {
     driver.findElement(By.className("btn btn-small")).click();
}

@Then("^User is on Home Page$")
public void user_is_on_Home_Page() {
   String tittle= driver.getTitle();
   System.out.println("tittle is : " + tittle );
   Assert.assertEquals("CRMPRO", tittle);
}

}
```

2. login.feature

```
Feature: Free CRM Login Feature

  Scenario: Free CRM Login Test Scenario

    Given User is already on login page
    When  Tittle of login page is Free CRM
    Then  User enters username and password
    Then  User clicks on login button
    Then User is on Home Page
```

3. testrunner.java

```
package MyRunner;

import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber;
import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        features = "/Users/nilesh.gupta/eclipse-workspace/CucumberBDD/src/main/java/Features/login.feature",
        glue={"stepDefinition"}
        /*format={"pretty","html:test-output"}*/
)
public class testRunner {
}
```

4. pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>CucumberBDD</groupId>
  <artifactId>CucumberBDD</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>CucumberBDD</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <cucumber.version>4.8.0</cucumber.version>
    <selenium.version>3.5.3</selenium.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>

       <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
            <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
        </dependency>

      <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>${selenium.version}</version>
        </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

5. Output

```
There were undefined steps. You can implement missing steps with the snippets below:

@Given("User is already on login page")
public void user_is_already_on_login_page() {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    throw new cucumber.api.PendingException();
}

@When("Tittle of login page is Free CRM")
public void tittle_of_login_page_is_Free_CRM() {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    throw new cucumber.api.PendingException();
}

@Then("User enters username and password")
public void user_enters_username_and_password() {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    throw new cucumber.api.PendingException();
}

@Then("User clicks on login button")
public void user_clicks_on_login_button() {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    throw new cucumber.api.PendingException();
}

@Then("User is on Home Page")
public void user_is_on_Home_Page() {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    throw new cucumber.api.PendingException();
}
```

Comment: Try `@CucumberOptions(features = "classpath:Features/login.feature",`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try to make habit to write testing code in the test folder `src/test/java` instead of `main` . Everything that write into `src/main/java` is per default packaged and deliver to your customer whereas everything that you put into `src/test/java` is no.

**Features** Options helps Cucumber to locate the Feature file in the project folder structure. 
if the Feature file is in the deep folder structure then please use features = “src/test/features“.

**Glue**
use to locate the Step Definition file.

Once you make changes then please refer below code for your runner file.

```
package MyRunner;   
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
 features = "src/test/features"
 ,glue={"src/test/stepDefinition"}
 ,monochrome = false
 )

public class testRunner {

}
```

Comment: thank you for the input. i will keep this in mind in future.

Comment: Can you please accept my answer and press upvote button ?

Answer (score 0):

Try, replace your code in Runner with this. Rebuild project and close and reopen it.

```
  package MyRunner;

    import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

    import io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber;
    import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions;

    @RunWith(Cucumber.class)
    @CucumberOptions(
            features = "src/main/java/Features/login.feature",
            glue={"StepDefinition"}
            /*format={"pretty","html:test-output"}*/
    )
    public class testRunner {
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example, I think the actual problem is that you cannot use anchors ^ or $ in your stepdefinitions' (Cucumber Expressions) and it shouldn't be there for newer version of io.cucumber. That style is used for info.cukes version.

It should be

```
@Given("User is already on login page")
public void user_already_on_login_page(){
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","/Users/nilesh.gupta/Desktop/chromedriver" );
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("https://classic.crmpro.com");    
}
```

Instead of

```
@Given("^User is already on login page$")
public void user_already_on_login_page(){
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","/Users/nilesh.gupta/Desktop/chromedriver" );
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("https://classic.crmpro.com");    
}
```